# Regex help advanced

Tags: regex

I have a regex problem

I need to validate a user given pre defined string to check if there are no mistakes in that string. I made unit test below the tests so you can see what string must match and what don't.
What i already have and works for most:

```
/^product:\[(.*?)\]|default:\[(.*?)\]$/
```

What still needs to be tested is there must not be any whitespaces this does not count for the values between the [] And the | must be there. but not at the end

```
return array(
        array(
            'default:[6_400]',
            TRUE
        ),
        array(
            'default:[bla_bla]',
            TRUE
        ),
        array(
            'default:[bla _ bla]',
            TRUE
        ),
        array(
            'product:8[8_400]|default:[6_400]',
            TRUE
        ),
        array(
            'product:8[8_400]|default:[6_400]|product:10[10_400]',
            TRUE
        ),
        array(
            'product:8[8_400]|product:12 [12_400]|default:[6_400]',
            FALSE
        ),
        array(
            'roduct:8[8_400]|product:12[12_400]|default[6_400',
            FALSE
        ),
        array(
            'default:6_400',
            FALSE
        ),
        array(
            'product:8[8_400]',
            FALSE
        ),
        array(
            'product:8[8_400]default:[6_400]',
            FALSE
        ),
        array(
            'product:8[8_400]|default:[6_400]|',
            FALSE
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your examples, I think you mean that inside the brackets you want word characters or spaces (you probably don't want #$%^&&, null and other such stuff)...

```
\[[\w\s]+\]
```

This apparently can be proceded by either product:number or default:

```
((product:\d+)|(default:))(\[[\w\s]+\])
```

Clauses must be separated by | but the matching string must not end with '|'

```
((product:\d+)|(default:))(\[[\w\s]+\])(\|(?!$)|$)
```

This can occur one or more times

```
(((product:\d+)|(default:))(\[[\w\s]+\])(\|(?!$)|$))+
```

And we must have at least one full, legal default clause:

```
(?=.*?default:\[[\w\s]+\])(((product:\d+)|(default:))(\[[\w\s]+\])(\|(?!$)|$))+
```

and fill the whole line:

```
^(?=.*?default:\[[\w\s]+\])(((product:\d+)|(default:))(\[[\w\s]+\])(\|(?!$)|$))+$
```

Here it is in action http://regexr.com?3275i

Note that since I have not included any patterns that allow white-space anywhere other than in the brackets, nothing special needs to be done to prohibit it outside of the brackets

Also note that I have created many capturing groups (for simplicity/readability) but you can eliminate them by placing ?: after any ( you don't want to capture. This improves performance somewhat. Besides testing things in regexr.com, this site is often helpful for learning/building regular expressions:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: thanks for the response this helped me out and it's indeed pretty nice to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/^(?=.*?default)(?:(?:product|default):\d*\[[^\]]*\](?:\|(?!$)|$))+$/
```

See on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/fxLinAimWH)

If you want to exclude the possibility that `default` might appear in the `[]`, as Gabber pointed out, you could use:

```
/^(?:product:\d*\[[^\]]*\]\|)?(?:default:\d*\[[^\]]*\](?:\|(?!$)|$))(?:product:\‌​d*\[[^\]]*\](?:\|(?!$)|$))?$/
```

Comment: quote _And why is product:8[8_400] FALSE ?_

Comment: This way default can also be in the `[]` (`product:[default]` would be ok)

Comment: True, if thats possible, the regex could look like this: `^(?=.*?default:\d*\[[^\]]*\])(?:(?:product|default):\d*\[[^\]]*\](?:\|(?!$)|$))+$` or `^(?:product:\d*\[[^\]]*\]\|)?(?:default:\d*\[[^\]]*\](?:\|(?!$)|$))(?:product:\d*\[[^\]]*\](?:\|(?!$)|$))?$`